# JQuery div will animate to the right when window scrolls down to it but not to the left (second time the animation is triggered)

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a document scroll event checking if a certain div is visible on the screen (plus an offset). when it is I want to slide that div in from the left.

Its position is set to relative and its left is initiated at -100%.

here is my code:

```
//animate bank logos when we scroll down
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var windowTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var bankLogos = $(".bank-logos");
    var bankLogosTop = bankLogos.offset().top;
    var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;


    if(windowTop >= (bankLogosTop - clientHeight + 130) && parseInt(bankLogos.css("left")) < 0) {
        bankLogos.animate({left: "0"}, 2000);
    } else if (windowTop < (bankLogosTop - clientHeight + 130) && parseInt(bankLogos.css("top")) == 0 ) {
        bankLogos.animate({left: "-100%"});
        console.log("away");
    }


});
```

when I scroll down to it it slides in but the problem is when I scroll back up it does not slide away. (pls not the console does log "away" so this is not a validation error.

sass:

```
.bank-logos {
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
}
```

Basically the div IS aniamting from left to right. i.e. This code is being executed:

```
if(windowTop >= (bankLogosTop - clientHeight + 130) && parseInt(bankLogos.css("left")) < 0) {
            bankLogos.animate({left: "0"}, 2000);
        }
```

but its not going back to -100% (sliding back into the left). So this code is not executing properly. it is however being reached because the console does log "away":

```
else if (windowTop < (bankLogosTop - clientHeight + 130) && parseInt(bankLogos.css("top")) == 0 ) {
        bankLogos.animate({left: "-100%"});
        console.log("away");
    }
```

I am basically having a second animation problem. The div slides in from the left to become visible. but will not slide back into the the left to hide.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code please? The HTML and css for the `bankLogos` element you're using, the rest of your JS (I'm asuming this is in a scroll event handler? what's `bankLogos` and `bankLogosTop` and `clientHeight`, `windowTop`, etc...). Give us a working demo that illustrates the problem so we don't have to guess what things are or what they do. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Posted. Apologies I had the wrong code to begin with. So basically what happens is the bankLogos.animate({left: "-100%"}) is being skipped. However console.log("away"); is not being skipped. So validation is working but for some reason the animation is not.

Comment: BTW bankLogos is just a div spanning whole width of page

Comment: Have you considered using waypoints.js? Its a much easier way to trigger animations on scroll

Comment: The animation IS being triggered. like I said "away" logs, so the codeblock where bankLogos.animate({left: "-100%"}); resides is being reached.